# How do you pass a string from the UISearchBar (in storyboard) in one view to another view? (need an example)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard

I'm trying to pass data from the UISearchBar object (can this object even do do this?) in storyboard in one view (my first view) to another view (a blank view). I have already made my two custom classes for the UIViewController for the prepareforsegue method but I have no idea what to put in the method besides the unique identifier for the segue I am trying to do. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not repeat your questions. You should update your original question if you are not getting the answer your need.

Comment: Sorry, I decided not to use classes, I will use edit next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    VCToPassTo *viewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    viewController.propertyToSet = self.searchBar.text;
}
```

That should do it, it'll grab the text property from the `UISearchBar` and then set the property on the destination view controller to it.

Comment: Thanks, is the variable name viewController in this case supposed to be the custom class I assigned to the VC that I'm passing from? And VCToPassTo, is it fine if its just the default UIViewController?

Comment: Yes `VCToPassTo` would be the name of your actual view controller.